# Unable to open a xls file in Openoffice 3.2

Tags: openoffice.org

I am unable to open a xls file in Openoffice 3.2. But the same file is getting Opened in other system which has the same Oo version. But in this When i open the file i get a pop-up window with
`Import Options => Select the language to use for import` and in that windows Automatic option is already choosed giving ok opens the file without any error. But this pop is not happening in the other system, instead it is showing the following screen. How do i fix it?

[image]

#### Update 1:

```
$ file Rad.xls 
Rad.xls: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

- Both the systems have displayed the same output. But in one system the file is getting opened, and in other its not opening. Both has the same version of `OpenOffice`.

Comment: Can you check with "file" from command line if you get the same results? That popup -should- ONLY show when the system thinks it is a csv file (defaults to semicolon in your screen) or a txt file (defaults to tab in your screen). And you say "xls"? But the image seems to show an HTML.

Comment: Do you mean the language or the character set? Character set is highlighted in blue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably these two systems have different locale settings for date, time and number format.

For example: one thousand is written as 1,000.00 (in the US) but in other countries 
(Europe) you would write 1.000,00.

In US the convention is mm/dd/yy but in Europe dd/mm/yy.

Check with System Settings - Language Support - Regional Formats

Also in OpenOffice, check Options - Language Settings - Languages

Answer (score 0):

It is not an XLS file.  You might try opening it as Spreadsheet XML, but you might try opening it in a browser and seeing what you can do with it.  On Windows, this might open in Excel because it was produced by Office and they can be take these back in.

Comment: It's not about opening this file in OpenOffice. It's about the pop-up screen.

Comment: The pop-up is because OpenOffice doesn't recognize this kind of file on its own and is attempting to figure out how to treat it as CSV.  Notice it is treating the <DOCTYPE> string as a first-line set of column headings, etc.